# Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" search engine on Chromium

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chromium 40 on Ubuntu 14.04 and basically I’ve had `fl` search engine for some time:

```
fl = http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I&q=%s
```

And it worked well till now. For example I could type `fl tv wiki shameless` and it took me directly to the Wikipedia page. As copy-paste URL it still works fine for me, but not as search engine. Funny thing is, though, typing fast enough helps.

Instead I get something like that:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#newwindow=1&q=gmail
```

Switching off “Predict network actions to improve page load performance” removed the issue. Seems they changed the its implementation(?) at some point, because I’ve had it on for some time. But I don’t want to lose faster load.

So the question is, can I still have prediction on but get to keep my feeling lucky custom search engine working?

Comment: As this is a question about Web browser functionality, it really belongs on [su]. I have voted to migrate.

Comment: @AlE. Yep you're right, just started as webapp question in my mind.

Comment: Did you find any solution how to use I'm Feeling Lucky from the omnibox?