# How can I search with Google's I'm Feeling Lucky feature directly from Chrome's omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, search, feeling-lucky

I searched Super User and found the following existing questions:

- [Google's “I'm Feeling Lucky” search engine on Chromium](https://superuser.com/questions/886889/googles-im-feeling-lucky-search-engine-on-chromium)
- [Chrome: Ctrl-K for Google Search, and Ctrl-L for I'm Feeling Lucky](https://superuser.com/questions/262925/chrome-ctrl-k-for-google-search-and-ctrl-l-for-im-feeling-lucky)
- [Google Chrome Shortcut Key for “I'm Feeling Lucky” [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/448175/google-chrome-shortcut-key-for-im-feeling-lucky)

None of the answers to these questions provide working solutions (as of today) to perform all searches in Chrome's omnibox (the box where you type in the URL) using Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" feature.

**Envisioned workflow:**

1. Put the cursor into the omnibox
2. Type your search term, e.g. coffee
3. The result returned by "I'm Feeling Lucky" should be directly opened in the tab

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding a new search engine to Google via the following worked for me:

> 1) Go to the Chrome Settings page and choose Search > Manage Search Engines
>
> 2) Go to add new search option. This might vary depending on what Chrome version you’re on, but you get the gist.
>
> 3) Give it a name, it doesn’t really matter what, I use “Go straight to”
>
> 4) Give it a shortcut key. This will tell Chrome you want to use the ‘Go straight to’ option. I use backslash “\”. So when you want to use Feeling Lucky, you type “\” followed a space and whatever name or term you want to go straight to.
>
> 5) In the third box for the URL, paste http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI

Source:
[https://nairnrobertson.com/2013/10/29/everyday-hacks-use-google-feeling-lucky-inchromes-search-bar/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314044210/https://nairnrobertson.com/2013/10/29/everyday-hacks-use-google-feeling-lucky-inchromes-search-bar/)

Note that as an alternative to step 1) you could copy and paste the following into a new tab:

```
chrome://settings/searchEngines?search=manage
```

Comment: FYI: This method now displays a **Redirect Notice**.

Comment: To avoid the redirection notice, this plugin works great: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-google-redirects/nlacgjiklmjjejlgoclnjhndjaiempdo

Comment: Or use https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!%s until Google fix it

Comment: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=\%s` is even better.

Answer (score 4):

Working updated for 2022: (Similar to Matthew's answer with corrected url that doesn't show a redirect notice)

- Press the 3 dots : - Than settings, than search for search and select manager search engines.
- Go to add new search site option.
- Give it a name, it doesn’t really matter what, I use "I'm Feeling Lucky"
- Give it a shortcut key. This will tell Chrome you want to use the    ‘Go straight to’ option. I use backslash `\`. So when you want to use
  Feeling Lucky, you type `\` followed a space and whatever name or
  term you want to go straight to. In the third box for the URL, paste
  https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=%s

Only disadvantage (or advantage) to this one is google won't redirect you to the page if it doesn't have high confidence it's the correct page. It will instead return search results. Seems to use google AI to determine weather to redirect you or not.
Examples:

- Searching `\ final fantasy VII remake` brings a google search page
- Searching `\ final fantasy VII remake wikipedia` brings up the exact wikipedia article
- Searching `\ final fantasy VII remake pcgw` brings up the exact pc gaming wiki article

Answer (score 0):

We can use DuckDuckGo (I’m feeling ducky) to open up the first URL from search results.

1. Go to the address bar.
2. Type `Duck...` and press `Tab`.
   Chrome autocompletes it except we are visiting it for the first time where we need to type `duckduckgo.com`
3. Prepend `\` before your query. For example, `\react site`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180621)

Comment: It does answer the question and works, but it uses DuckDuckGo's lucky instead of Google's lucky.